# GET request to jsw file in Wix backend resulting in 404, File Not Found

Tags: velo

I am trying to make a GET request with Postman to a .jsw file I created in my Wix site's backend. I created the .jsw file by turning on dev mode. Clicking on the left-hand toolbar on the Public & Backend button. Then I created the .jsw in the Backend section.

I am trying to access this file from another front-end application I made. The URL for the path I am sending the GET request to is:

`https://www.mywebsite.com/_functions/myAPI`

I am basically trying to access a table in my Wix database from an external website. Here is how the code looks in my .jsw for accessing my table data.

```js
import {ok, created, notFound, serverError} from 'wix-http-functions';
import wixData from 'wix-data';

export async function get_myAPI(request) {
    const options = {
        "suppressAuth": true,
        "suppressHooks": true
    };

    try {
        const results = await wixData.query("Registrations").find(options);
        const data = results.items.map(item => {
            return {
                firstName: item.firstName,
                lastName: item.lastName,
                phone: item.phone,
                email: item.email,
                streetAddress: item.streetAddress,
                city: item.city,
                regionStateProvince: item.regionStateProvince,
                country: item.country,
                postalZipCode: item.postalZipCode,
                longAnswerField: item.paragraphField,
                shortAnswerField: item.shortAnswerField
            };
        });

        const response = ok({ body: { data } });
        response.headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://my-website.io", 
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With", 
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
        };

        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        const response = serverError({ body: { error: error.message } });
        response.headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://my-website.io", 
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With", 
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
        };

        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was my code should've been in an 'http-functions.js' file. In order to send requests to your Wix sites backend from an external website, you need to use an 'http-functions.js' file. My code worked correctly once I moved the code into the correct file name.